# Multiple commands produce error GTMSession

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I would like to archive my project so I can upload it to Apple-Connect but I am facing this issue:

[image]

I also get this these messages:

[image]

I googled it and I found that this is quite a common issue, which you can usually resolve by deleting a `info.plist` file from `Build Phase`.

However there is no such a file in the regarding `Build Phases`.

These are my pods for `GTM`:

[image]

`Build Phase` for `GTMSessionFetcher-Core`:

[image]

`Build Phase` for `GTMSessionFetcher.default-Core`:

[image]

My `podfile`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Wishlists' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Wishlists

    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    #pod 'TextFieldEffects'
    pod 'Hero'
    pod 'RevealingSplashView'
    pod 'LBTAComponents'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
    pod 'SwiftEntryKit', '1.2.3'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'SkeletonView'
    pod 'SwiftSoup'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.0'
    pod 'KeychainAccess'

end

target 'ShareExtension' do 
 
 use_frameworks!

    pod 'SwiftSoup'
    pod 'URLEmbeddedView'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.0'  

end
```

I really don't know much about this stuff so I don't want to delete anything by accident. Does anyone know what to do here?

Comment: I found the cause. pod 'Firebase/Auth' and pod 'GoogleSignIn' duplicated. you can delete one.