# Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

This is the full warning I get:

> Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework GTMSessionFetcher'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Wishlists' from project 'Wishlists')

What is the reason for this and how can I resolve it? This also leads to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65022431/multiple-commands-produce-error-gtmsession) error.

I have a Main-App and a ShareExtension.

This is my `podfile`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Wishlists' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Wishlists

    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    #pod 'TextFieldEffects'
    pod 'Hero'
    pod 'RevealingSplashView'
    pod 'LBTAComponents'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
    pod 'SwiftEntryKit', '1.2.3'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'SkeletonView'
    pod 'SwiftSoup'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.0'
    pod 'KeychainAccess'


# add pods for desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods 

end

target 'ShareExtension' do 
 
 use_frameworks!

    pod 'SwiftSoup'
    pod 'URLEmbeddedView'
    pod 'lottie-ios'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.0'  

end
```

I also have two `GoogleService-info-plist` files, one for the Main-App and one for the Share Extension.

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

**Update: Podfile.lock**

```
PODS:
  - abseil/algorithm (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/algorithm/container (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/algorithm/algorithm (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/algorithm/container (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/atomic_hook (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/base (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/base_internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/bits (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/config (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/core_headers (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/endian (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/errno_saver (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/exponential_biased (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/log_severity (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/malloc_internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/periodic_sampler (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/pretty_function (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/spinlock_wait (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/atomic_hook (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/base (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/atomic_hook
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations
    - abseil/base/log_severity
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/base/spinlock_wait
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base/base_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base/bits (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/config (0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/core_headers (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations (0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/endian (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/errno_saver (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/base/exponential_biased (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/log_severity (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/malloc_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/base/periodic_sampler (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/exponential_biased
  - abseil/base/pretty_function (0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/atomic_hook
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/log_severity
  - abseil/base/spinlock_wait (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/errno_saver
  - abseil/base/throw_delegate (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/container/compressed_tuple (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/container/inlined_vector (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate
    - abseil/container/inlined_vector_internal
    - abseil/memory/memory
  - abseil/container/inlined_vector_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/container/compressed_tuple
    - abseil/memory/memory
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/span
  - abseil/memory (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/memory/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/memory/memory (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/meta (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/meta/type_traits (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/meta/type_traits (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/numeric/int128 (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/strings/internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/endian
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/strings/str_format (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/strings/str_format_internal
  - abseil/strings/str_format_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/numeric/int128
    - abseil/strings/strings
    - abseil/types/span
  - abseil/strings/strings (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/bits
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/endian
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate
    - abseil/memory/memory
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/numeric/int128
    - abseil/strings/internal
  - abseil/time (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/time/internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/time/time (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/time/internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time
  - abseil/time/time (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/numeric/int128
    - abseil/strings/strings
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone
  - abseil/types (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/types/any (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_optional_access (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_variant_access (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/compare (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/optional (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/span (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/variant (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/types/any (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/types/bad_any_cast (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl
  - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/types/bad_optional_access (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/types/bad_variant_access (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/types/compare (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/types/optional (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/memory/memory
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_optional_access
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/types/span (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/types/variant (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_variant_access
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/utility/utility (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - AppAuth (1.4.0):
    - AppAuth/Core (= 1.4.0)
    - AppAuth/ExternalUserAgent (= 1.4.0)
  - AppAuth/Core (1.4.0)
  - AppAuth/ExternalUserAgent (1.4.0)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Implementation (= 0.0.7)
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (= 0.0.7)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC/Implementation (0.0.7):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (= 0.0.7)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (0.0.7)
  - FBSDKCoreKit (8.2.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (= 8.2.0)
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Core (= 8.2.0)
  - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (8.2.0)
  - FBSDKCoreKit/Core (8.2.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit/Basics
  - FBSDKLoginKit (8.2.0):
    - FBSDKLoginKit/Login (= 8.2.0)
  - FBSDKLoginKit/Login (8.2.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 8.2.0)
  - FBSDKShareKit (8.2.0):
    - FBSDKShareKit/Share (= 8.2.0)
  - FBSDKShareKit/Share (8.2.0):
    - FBSDKCoreKit (~> 8.2.0)
  - Firebase/Analytics (7.1.0):
    - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Auth (7.1.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 7.1.0)
  - Firebase/Core (7.1.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 7.1.0)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (7.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 7.1.0)
  - Firebase/Crashlytics (7.1.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 7.1.0)
  - Firebase/Database (7.1.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseDatabase (~> 7.1.0)
  - Firebase/Firestore (7.1.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseFirestore (~> 7.1.0)
  - Firebase/Storage (7.1.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseStorage (~> 7.1.0)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (7.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 7.1.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.0)"
    - nanopb (~> 2.30906.0)
  - FirebaseAuth (7.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.4)
  - FirebaseCore (7.1.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.0)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (7.1.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 8.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.0)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30906.0)
  - FirebaseCrashlytics (7.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 8.0)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30906.0)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - FirebaseDatabase (7.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.22)
  - FirebaseFirestore (7.1.0):
    - abseil/algorithm (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/meta (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/strings (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/time (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types (= 0.20200225.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
    - "gRPC-C++ (~> 1.28.0)"
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.22)
    - nanopb (~> 2.30906.0)
  - FirebaseInstallations (7.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.0)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - FirebaseStorage (7.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.4)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (7.1.0):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.0)"
    - nanopb (~> 2.30906.0)
  - GoogleDataTransport (8.0.1):
    - nanopb (~> 2.30906.0)
  - GoogleSignIn (5.0.2):
    - AppAuth (~> 1.2)
    - GTMAppAuth (~> 1.0)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (7.1.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (7.1.1):
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (7.1.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (7.1.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (7.1.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (7.1.1)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (7.1.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (7.1.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - "gRPC-C++ (1.28.2)":
    - "gRPC-C++/Implementation (= 1.28.2)"
    - "gRPC-C++/Interface (= 1.28.2)"
  - "gRPC-C++/Implementation (1.28.2)":
    - abseil/container/inlined_vector (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/memory/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/str_format (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/strings (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/optional (= 0.20200225.0)
    - "gRPC-C++/Interface (= 1.28.2)"
    - gRPC-Core (= 1.28.2)
  - "gRPC-C++/Interface (1.28.2)"
  - gRPC-Core (1.28.2):
    - gRPC-Core/Implementation (= 1.28.2)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.28.2)
  - gRPC-Core/Implementation (1.28.2):
    - abseil/container/inlined_vector (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/memory/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/str_format (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/strings (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/optional (= 0.20200225.0)
    - BoringSSL-GRPC (= 0.0.7)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.28.2)
  - gRPC-Core/Interface (1.28.2)
  - GTMAppAuth (1.1.0):
    - AppAuth/Core (~> 1.4)
    - GTMSessionFetcher (~> 1.4)
  - GTMSessionFetcher (1.5.0):
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Full (= 1.5.0)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.5.0)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Full (1.5.0):
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (= 1.5.0)
  - Hero (1.5.0)
  - KeychainAccess (4.2.1)
  - Kingfisher (5.15.7):
    - Kingfisher/Core (= 5.15.7)
  - Kingfisher/Core (5.15.7)
  - LBTAComponents (1.1)
  - leveldb-library (1.22)
  - lottie-ios (3.1.9)
  - nanopb (2.30906.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 2.30906.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 2.30906.0)
  - nanopb/decode (2.30906.0)
  - nanopb/encode (2.30906.0)
  - PromisesObjC (1.2.11)
  - QuickLayout (3.0.0)
  - RevealingSplashView (0.6.0)
  - SkeletonView (1.11.0)
  - SwiftEntryKit (1.2.3):
    - QuickLayout (= 3.0.0)
  - SwiftSoup (2.3.2)
  - URLEmbeddedView (0.18.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - FBSDKCoreKit
  - FBSDKLoginKit
  - FBSDKShareKit
  - Firebase/Analytics
  - Firebase/Auth
  - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Crashlytics
  - Firebase/Database
  - Firebase/Firestore
  - Firebase/Storage
  - GoogleSignIn
  - Hero
  - KeychainAccess
  - Kingfisher (~> 5.0)
  - LBTAComponents
  - lottie-ios
  - RevealingSplashView
  - SkeletonView
  - SwiftEntryKit (= 1.2.3)
  - SwiftSoup
  - URLEmbeddedView

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - abseil
    - AppAuth
    - BoringSSL-GRPC
    - FBSDKCoreKit
    - FBSDKLoginKit
    - FBSDKShareKit
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseAuth
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseCrashlytics
    - FirebaseDatabase
    - FirebaseFirestore
    - FirebaseInstallations
    - FirebaseStorage
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleSignIn
    - GoogleUtilities
    - "gRPC-C++"
    - gRPC-Core
    - GTMAppAuth
    - GTMSessionFetcher
    - Hero
    - KeychainAccess
    - Kingfisher
    - LBTAComponents
    - leveldb-library
    - lottie-ios
    - nanopb
    - PromisesObjC
    - QuickLayout
    - RevealingSplashView
    - SkeletonView
    - SwiftEntryKit
    - SwiftSoup
    - URLEmbeddedView

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  abseil: 6c8eb7892aefa08d929b39f9bb108e5367e3228f
  AppAuth: 31bcec809a638d7bd2f86ea8a52bd45f6e81e7c7
  BoringSSL-GRPC: 8edf627ee524575e2f8d19d56f068b448eea3879
  FBSDKCoreKit: 4afd6ff53d8133a433dbcda44451c9498f8c6ce4
  FBSDKLoginKit: 7181765f2524d7ebf82d9629066c8e6caafc99d0
  FBSDKShareKit: 0c0d51b3af47075a85ed9bea0e28b2fc70e3594b
  Firebase: 78e8dd2e39d653de6270432ad84fe8b59f7bf4e8
  FirebaseAnalytics: 7f165a56dea86ddd5b8ce02af3bee982c683405c
  FirebaseAuth: f82c2cfcc1c107bb0a97735cdbce4eb2a601f710
  FirebaseCore: 20046127eef0fcb8fa25df7fc12f7b97d4e48611
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: 872cdb9b749b23346dddd5c1014d1babd2257de3
  FirebaseCrashlytics: c722e4ca283272eb90eb5bc245fdc6588e2f22c2
  FirebaseDatabase: bf02ea57590aaab4e72b9b12b412a4c881ee81e2
  FirebaseFirestore: bbf303f0638a93e6ecb38433aad283cebdfece5f
  FirebaseInstallations: 3de38553e86171b5f81d83cdeef63473d37bfdb0
  FirebaseStorage: 80e2cd5200791540ca544f4dcac5e6b56994fc97
  GoogleAppMeasurement: 89e1a64593f968713b0506ba1b53b38a154bf9a5
  GoogleDataTransport: e4085e6762f36a6141738f46b0153473ce57fb18
  GoogleSignIn: 7137d297ddc022a7e0aa4619c86d72c909fa7213
  GoogleUtilities: 3dc4ff0d5e4840e2fa8eef0889620e8c33d4218c
  "gRPC-C++": 13d8ccef97d5c3c441b7e3c529ef28ebee86fad2
  gRPC-Core: 4afa11bfbedf7cdecd04de535a9e046893404ed5
  GTMAppAuth: 197a8dabfea5d665224aa00d17f164fc2248dab9
  GTMSessionFetcher: b3503b20a988c4e20cc189aa798fd18220133f52
  Hero: b7385b75e7259da62f4f85462f59a5082d66b058
  KeychainAccess: 9b07f665298d13c3a85881bd3171f6f49b8151c1
  Kingfisher: 6e1a13523fcb1c86924ce53affe4ac957e544d59
  LBTAComponents: 2e7719683ddcf1cdf7280700438c0c6a5f7da550
  leveldb-library: 55d93ee664b4007aac644a782d11da33fba316f7
  lottie-ios: 3a3758ef5a008e762faec9c9d50a39842f26d124
  nanopb: 1bf24dd71191072e120b83dd02d08f3da0d65e53
  PromisesObjC: 8c196f5a328c2cba3e74624585467a557dcb482f
  QuickLayout: 07b45a72b10083fee3f095990cfed1c1e7b27f0a
  RevealingSplashView: 40c5a770894459736acdc95655eeba0dd30ce91c
  SkeletonView: cc84ce90a804dd0dd7198dd802833411c8a64eaf
  SwiftEntryKit: 340713c2e4a6662c5149629990bf1088bf5f0389
  SwiftSoup: f97bc4e988c7729d6457f9642f974c617a6e2510
  URLEmbeddedView: 3fe17ae535d2b8d38c3b08ab8ba0aea5efe5d1cd

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 3655de5895768181742f054191e325e1c90977d8

COCOAPODS: 1.8.4
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This happens when a Podfile has multiple targets, each of which has an implicit dependency on another pod.

The solution is to make that dependency explicit, at the top level. In your case, that means inserting the following:

```
pod 'GTMSessionFetcher'
```

see [github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8206](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8206) for more discussion

Comment: i am facing similar issue, can you tell me what to do @mr.fixit
Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flag '-lRNVectorIcons'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'xUI' from project 'xUI')